# Diferença de performance ao Duplicar uma tabela

Tags: sql, sql-server

Existe diferença significativa de performance entre esses dois exemplos?

```
SELECT * INTO  [IP].BA_exemplo.dbo.TabelaB  
FROM BA_Temp..TabelaA
```

e

```
SELECT A,B,C,D... -- (todos os campos da tabela `TabelaA`)
INTO  [IP].BA_exemplo.dbo.TabelaB
FROM  BA_Temp..TabelaA
```

para usar em uma `procedure`

Comment: Se não estou em erro ambos os exemplos fazem a mesma coisa. Se no 2º exemplo colocasse apenas uma parte das colunas, aí sim, poderia haver diferenças de _performance_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Existe diferença significativa de performance entre esses dois exemplos?
>   ...
>
>   para usar em uma procedure*

Não.

Nenhuma diferença de performance.

Internamente é gerado o mesmo plano de execução, nos dois casos, com o mesmo conteúdo na propriedade "Lista de Saída" do operador de leitura. No artigo “[O Plano Perfeito](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/11/21/o-plano-perfeito/)” há explicação do que é o plano de execução, como gerá-lo e interpretação básica do mesmo.

Comment: Obrigado José Diz, gostei bastante do seu artigo. Valeu!

Answer (score 0):

Estou de acordo com o joão, a unica diferença que afeta a performançe é justamente estares a usar o `*` o que vai trazer todas as colunas, o que é uma má pratica, e ao trazer todas as colunas o SQL não tem informação se pode optar pelo uso de um dado indice.

Por exemplo, se tiveres uma tabela com 10 colunas (C1, C2 ... C10) e tiveres um indice na coluna "C1" ao fazer `SELECT C1, C2 FROM Tabela C=1` o SQL usa o indice porque sabe onde procurar a informação. Pelo contrario de fizeres `SELECT * FROM Tabela C=1` não o pode fazer.

Mais `SELECT *` não é um padrão de escrita recomendado porque:

- Se especificares colunas numa instrução o mecanismo de execução SQL dá e rro se essa coluna for removida da tabela.
- Deves sempre escrever consultas que devolvam o mínimo de dados.
- Se tiveres de usar joins entre tabelas, * dá todas as colunas detodas as tabelas do join

Comment: Embora utilizar `SELECT *` seja um péssimo hábito, me parece que ele não influencia na utilização ou não de índice, caso o índice seja clustered e o predicado na cláusula WHERE contenha a coluna que é chave primária. No caso de `SELECT * from Tabela where C1 = 1`, ocorrerá seek se o índice for clustered e pela coluna C1.

Comment: Certo @JoséDiz, mas neste caso ele não refere cláusula `WHERE`, logo isso não se aplica ao cenário.

Comment: @JoãoMartins Meu comentário foi postado diretamente na resposta do Sérgio por esta conter afirmação que não é correta.

Comment: @JoséDiz na minha resposta assumi que as colunas não eram indice clustered. Vou atualizar a resposta para não ficarem duvidas